# Facebook keeps rejecting application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My company's Facebook app has been in operation for a few years, but with the recent API upgrade, Facebook now requires apps to be submitted for approval if you need certain permissions.

This app adds a page tab, which requires the `manage_pages` permission. Facebook has rejected the app several times, providing the following reason:

> We could not reproduce the requested permission. Please submit
>   detailed, step-by-step English instructions in the "Add Notes" section
>   of the permission, and make sure to provide the relevant version of
>   your app.

Things I've done:

- provided step-by-step instructions, with supporting screenshots for each step
- had multiple people test those steps to ensure the login process and page tab work as expected
- read through all of the supporting documentation and submission articles

Unfortunately, Facebook provides no option to contact their reviewers.

Has anyone else hit a wall when submitting a Facebook app for approval? And if so, were you able to figure out the issue or contact the reviewer?

Answer (score 2):

That's unfortunate... I think there have been such cases. If you think everything is correct with your review submission, I'd recommend that you post a message to https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ There are FB engineers monitoring the group, I guess they could give you some help or contact the right persons.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to resolve such issues. Don’t forget to include your app id in your question, so that the FB staff reading along there can check out the issue directly.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestions. I've requested to join the group and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Learned on the Facebook Developers group that they encourage apps to use the "Add Page Tab Dialog" to accomplish this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/page-tab-dialog

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would be nice to find this in the documentation somewhere, ideally at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference